# Validating datetime fields in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, date, datetime

I have three AJAX calendar controls (start date, end date and effective date) for in my project. Which selects date in the format dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt. I want to add a following client side validations :

1. end date should be greater than or equal to start date.
2. effective date should be greater than end date.

I have tried using CompareValidator but it did not help as it do not allow me to compare time.

Is there any workaround to achieve this validation on client side.

Comment: Can you post a sample for `StartDate/EndDate/EffectiveDate`? I assume you are facing with `conversion of the Date objects`.

Comment: Converting the value to Date type gives strange result. Following is the result immediate window output: ?document.getElementById("txtCompletionDate").value "10/12/2014 12:37:21 PM" ?new Date(document.getElementById("txtCompletionDate").value) Sun Oct 12 12:37:21 UTC+0530 2014 [prototype]: Invalid Date Is there any way to specify the date format while converting value to Date type?

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it like this using jquery**

```
//First check that textboxes are not empty
if($('input[id$=txtEndDate]').val()=="")
{
//Enter end date
return;
}
var endDate=new Date($('input[id$=txtEndDate]').val());
var startDate=new Date($('input[id$=txtStartDate]').val());
var effctDate=new Date($('input[id$=txtEffectiveDate]').val());

if(endDate>=startDate)
{
 //your code
}
else
{

}
if(effctDate>endDate)
{
 //your code
}
else
{

}
```

**Using Javascript**

```
//First check that textboxes are not empty
if(document.getElementById("txtEndDate").value=="")
{
//Enter end date
return;
}
var endDate=new Date(document.getElementById("txtEndDate").value);
var startDate=new Date(document.getElementById("txtStartDate").value);
var effctDate=new Date(document.getElementById("txtEffectiveDate").value);

if(endDate>=startDate)
{
 //your code
}
else
{

}
if(effctDate>endDate)
{
 //your code
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but i am receiving "JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined.

Comment: You need to add Jquery file in your page

Comment: @MandarPatil have you added the jquery file ?

Comment: Using JavaScript did not give any error. But converting the value to Date type gives strange result. Following is the result immediate window output: 
?document.getElementById("txtCompletionDate").value
"10/12/2014 12:37:21 PM"

?new Date(document.getElementById("txtCompletionDate").value)
Sun Oct 12 12:37:21 UTC+0530 2014
    [prototype]: Invalid Date

Is there any way to specify the date format while converting value to Date type?

Comment: do not allow time in texboxes only allow date.

Comment: I have this as requirement where user is required to enter time along with date. I think issue is not with the time part but with the format of the date which is dd/MM/yyyy mm:hh:ss tt. That is why 10/12/2014 12:37:21 PM is getting converted as Sun Oct 12 12:37:21.